# MySQL Cascade delete if one-to-one relationship

Tags: mysql, data-modeling, delete-row, one-to-one

Imagine a database that stores book titles and authors. When I delete a book title, I also want to delete the author - but only if they have no other book titles associated with them.

Is there a way to do that?

Or, perhaps, you can recommend how I'd structure my tables differently to get around this. This is a simplified example of an app where I'm in charge of the data modelling; perhaps by asking the above question I've clearly structured my data poorly.

Comment: Which one is parent table here? You will have to write this logic in code. Database may not provide custom logic for cascade deletion?

Comment: This isn't a one-to-one relationship, it's one-to-many, since an author can have many books. You can't do this with cascade, you can do it with a trigger.

Comment: Though you're absolutely correct Barmar, my use of one-to-one was an effort to label the scenario (describing one-to-one as "if the book I'm deleting is the last relation to an author") that could in theory trigger a cascade hook. Uueerdo introduced me to the concept of an AFTER DELETE trigger, which sounds like the best solution for my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those "chicken and egg" data modeling scenarios like a department needing employees, and a department's manager being an employee in the department. Normally, you'd think of the author as the "parent" since it can have many books and book must be authored; but without a book that they have authored, they are not an author.

So it is not really a poor structure, so much as a complication of the relationship you are representing. CASCADE will not work for you; but you could use an AFTER DELETE trigger on your "books" table to check if the author of the deleted book has any books remaining and delete them if they don't.